# Implementing an Unbounded Min Priority Queue using a Singly Linked List in Python

Tags: python, function, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am doing a class project and I have to implement an unbounded singly linked list using python. I need to implement a given 'insert' that has to consider the following cases...

insert into an empty queue
insert at the front of the queue
insert after some existing node.

This is the class given in python and i need to implement the insert function given at the bottom.
I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class CinemaPriorityQueue:
    """A linked list implementation of an unbounded min-priority queue."""

    class Node:
        """A node in a linked list."""

        def __init__(self, item: object, priority_value: int) -> None:
            """Initialise the node with the given item and priority value."""
            self.item = item
            self.priority = priority_value
            self.next = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Initialise the queue to be empty."""
        self.head = None

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        """
        Preconditions: true
        Postconditions: the output is true if the queue is empty, false otherwise
        """
        return self.head == None

    def print(self) -> None:
        """Print out the queue"""
        if self.head == None:
            print('The queue is empty')
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current != None:
                print(current.item, current.priority)
                current = current.next



    def insert(self, item: object, priority_value: int) -> None:
        """Insert item according to priority.
        Preconditions: true
        Postconditions: post-self is the sequence
        pre-self with item inserted after
        the last item in self with the same priority
        """
        pass
        #*Write your code solution here*
```

Comment: Looking at the code you provided, it seems there is not a single line that you have written so far. We appreciate questions that show effort. This is not such a question.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you the idea behind the solution. In the singly linked list, while adding a new element, compare it with the elements in the linked list and add it where it fits so that the linked list is sorted. This will give you a min priority queue.

Comment: This is a very good hint without actually giving the ready made answer away. Upvoted!